# Why "X-Forwarded-For" and "Via" headers missing when resource is requested by https?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, kestrel, x-forwarded-for

I am building an Asp.Net Core web application. I have created a resource that returns request headers as json. I assume, that when I request this resource through transparent proxy server (from list https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/transparent-proxies/) that is guaranteed to add X-Forwarded-For and Via headers to request, I will see those headers in the response's json:

Request:
https://res.cloudinary.com/leninsdo/image/upload/v1550267036/1_vmfx0z.png

Response:
https://res.cloudinary.com/leninsdo/image/upload/v1550267039/2_dtftny.png

But when I request EXACTLY THE SAME resource WITH THE SAME PROXY over https I do not see those headers in the response:

Request: https://res.cloudinary.com/leninsdo/image/upload/v1550267251/3_qlifuv.png

Response: https://res.cloudinary.com/leninsdo/image/upload/v1550267313/4.png

I use Kestrel as a web server and configured it in Program.cs in this way:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .UseKestrel(options =>
      {
           options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
           options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);
           options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
           {
                listenOptions.UseHttps(CertFilename, CertPassword);
           });
      })
      .UseSetting("https_port", "443")
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .Build();
```

The code in the controller which iterates over headers and serilizes them into json is also very usual and doesn't seem to be the source of the problem:

```
List<Header> headers = new List<Header>(); //later returned in json
foreach(var key in context.Request.Headers.Keys)
{
    var values = StringValues.Empty;
    Request.Headers.TryGetValue(key, out values);
    headers.Add(new Header{ //my custom class with two fields - Key and Value
        Key = key,
        Value = (String) Convert.ChangeType(values.ToString(),typeof(String))
    });
}
```

And I have completely no idea why headers Via and X-Forwarded-For disappear when resource requested over https instead of http. I've tested it with a great variety of proxies from many different sites - the result is the same.

Can someone tell me why this can happen?

Comment: I believe proxy can't insert content into SSL traffic without reencrypting/Men-In-the-Middle...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i've googled some info on this topic and it seems to me you're right... and I will not be able to get proxy info if my webapp is accessed with https